# i can't increment using the forEach method in java

Tags: java, java-8

i can't increment the values in the list using the foreach method

```
List<Integer>l=new ArrayList<Integer>();

    l.add(1);
    l.add(2);
    l.forEach(k->k=new Integer(k.intValue()+1));
     
          
    l.forEach((k->System.out.println(k)));
```

what is strange that printing values inside the list works fine.

and am asking this because using this method is supposed to be faster than the casual for loops
like this one:

```
List<Integer>l=new ArrayList<Integer>();
l.add(1);
    l.add(2);
   for(int i=0;i<l.size();i++){
       l.set(i, l.get(i)+1);
   }
     
       
          
    l.forEach((k->System.out.println(k)));
```

Comment: Using `forEach` is actually slower than a for Loop...

Comment: you mean the forEach method or the loop?

Comment: because it is supposed to save some work for me

Comment: Use map instead.

Comment: it works with maps not lists?

Comment: map function != Map object

Comment: if i may ask what is a map function

Comment: I trust your ability to search the JavaDoc for that

Comment: for loop is faster than both forEach function and for each loop

Comment: okay thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` has no side-effects. It simply iterates and has a `void` return type, meaning noting updates in the original list/stream using it.

Here is the *actual* code that runs

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.forEach(new Consumer<Integer>() {
     @Override
     public void accept(Integer integer) {
        integer+=1;  // notice, no return
     }
 });
```

You want to use `l.stream().map(k -> k + 1)` to update each element

```
l.stream().map(new Function<Integer, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(Integer integer) {
        return integer + 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: i get the first code because i wrote it and it runs but i didn't get why it doesn't run with the lambada expression
and i don't know what stream is sorry

Comment: Well, what is a list or a collection? What about a stream don't you understand? They are the same thing, but Java 8 could not add `java.util.Stream` class without breaking backwards compatibility, so they added a `.stream()` method to convert them and add more methods there

Comment: okay i will read the stream documentation 
i just knew what is stream and what it does
i didn't know that forEach() is part of the whole stream thing 
i was just trying the different methods inside every collection and it got me here
thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use Stream API. Use `map()` to increment the value of list and then collect as list and assign list.

```
l = l.stream().map(k -> k+1).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: okay i will look it up and read the documentation thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it e.g. you can use `IntStream` as shown below:

```
IntStream.range(0, l.size()).forEachOrdered(i -> l.set(i, l.get(i) + 1));
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();

        // Add some integers to the list
        l.add(1);
        l.add(2);

        // Increment elements by 1
        IntStream.range(0, l.size()).forEachOrdered(i -> l.set(i, l.get(i) + 1));

        // Display
        l.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2
3
```